# EF How to make in one request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have the following architecture:

1. Standard ASP.NET Identity tables, user can have one and only one role
2. There are 2 roles : Driver and Manager
3. User has driver or manager role. Every driver has record in Driver table, Every manager has record in Manager table.
4. Both, Manager and Driver tables, has FirstName and LastName

My entities and map among them (0..1:1):

```
public class AspNetUser 
{
    //.....
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; } 
}


public partial class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //....
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //....
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}

    public class AspNetUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AspNetUser>
    {
        public AspNetUserMap()
        {
            this.HasKey(dp => dp.Id);
            this.Property(p => p.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
            this.HasIndex(p => p.UserName).IsClustered(false).IsUnique();

            this.HasOptional(c => c.Driver)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(a => a.AspNetUser)
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("AspNetUserId"));

            this.HasOptional(c => c.Manager)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(a => a.AspNetUser)
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("AspNetUserId"));
```

Now I need to get all users from AspNetUser, but with their FN/LN. To get FN/LN I should check role of user and then call Driver or Manager.

I have the following code:

```
        List<ChatUserDomain> returnedUsers = new List<ChatUserDomain>();
        var users = (from i in db.AspNetUsers
                     .Include(path => path.Driver)
                     .Include(path => path.Manager)
                     .Include(path => path.AspNetRoles)
                     where i.CompanyId == db.AspNetUsers.Where(p => p.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault().CompanyId 
                     select new
                     {
                         AspNetUser = i,
                         Username = i.UserName,
                         ....
                     }
                     ).ToList();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            returnedUsers.Add(new ChatUserDomain()
            {
                UserId = user.AspNetUser.Id,
                Name = GetNameByUser(user.AspNetUser),
                ...
            });
        }
        return returnedUsers;
```

and GetNameByUser method:

```
    private string GetNameByUser(AspNetUser aspNetUser)
    {
        IProfile profile = GetProfileByUser(aspNetUser);

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(profile.FirstName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(profile.LastName))
        {
            return (GetFirstLettersOfFullName(profile.FirstName, profile.LastName));
        }
        else
        {
            return (aspNetUser.UserName.Substring(0, 2));
        }
    }

    private IProfile GetProfileByUser(AspNetUser aspNetUser)
    {
        IProfile profile = null;
        var role = aspNetUser.AspNetRoles.FirstOrDefault().Name;
        if (role.Equals(Domain.StaticStrings.RoleStaticStrings.ROLE_DRIVER))
            profile = aspNetUser.Driver;
        else
            profile = aspNetUser.Manager;

        return profile;
    }
```

It works, but it creates additional user.Count calls to DB. How to say to EF "load Manager and Driver data in the parent request"?

Comment: Forgive me if this question misses the point but you said "Both, Manager and Driver tables, has FirstName and LastName" - in that case why not just put those properties in the base table AspNetUser?

Comment: @AdamBenson because AspNetUser stores also additional types of users, which does not have FN/LN (I removed it to do my example as simplest as possible)

Comment: Sounds like Table per Type. This can produce simple-looking EF queries but the SQL it generates can be horrible. Anyway, maybe this will help: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt